# htaccess effects all index pages, need only the root index page effected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code to forward the root index page like the following:

www.domain.com/index.php?foo=value -> www.domain.com/value

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is this forwards all my index pages to the main page and I really only want this code to effect the root.

I figured it would be as simple as adding the domain as part of the rule but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?foo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Once again, thanks a bundle! How'd you get so good at url-rewrites, just plenty of experience?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. I don't write any rewrite rules myself on production systems but I just love to work on regex problems and most of these rules are just regex problems.